# How can I catch a connection refused error in a proper way?

Tags: python

In my code, I've made some post requests. How can I catch connection refused error in that call?

```
   try:
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        response = requests.request("POST", local_wallet_api + "v1/wallet/get_public_keys", headers=headers)
        res = json.loads(response.text)


   except Exception as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
            print("connection refused")
            sys.exit(141)
```

I've tried the above code, but it is not working as it says `e` has no `errno` parameter. Is there any proper way to handle this kind of error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError


   try:
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        response = requests.request("POST", local_wallet_api + "v1/wallet/get_public_keys", headers=headers)
        res = json.loads(response.text)

   except ConnectionError:
        sys.exit(141)
```

Comment: Ok, thank u. I've tried this, but I haven't imported that error class. That's why the exception wasn't fired

Comment: why it does not work if I do not do the import and catch the ConnectionError directly ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `requests.exceptions.RequestException` as your exception.

Example:

```
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # exception here
```

For the list of requests exceptions, check requests.exception documentation. You can refer to this [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370436/get-errno-from-python-requests-connectionerror).

you can get the errno by `e.args[0].reason.errno`.

also use this except:

```
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` didn't worked for me.

What is worked:

```py
import builtins
try:
    mysocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
except builtins.ConnectionRefusedError:
    pass # some error handling code should be implemented here
```