# requests.get connection refuse error (exception) not catched

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

Im trying to catch connection error when calling http get in a Python script.
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414137/how-can-i-catch-a-connection-refused-error-in-a-proper-way) descussing the exact same issue

For me, in 99% of the calls are going smooth. but every once in a while it seems the server refuses connection, but i am not able to catch that specific error, when is happens. Other exceptions are catched.

```
import requests
import sys
params = {
    "pair": "xbtusd",
    "interval": 5
}

url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC"
try:
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print("get requests.ConnectionError: " + str(sys.exc_info()[0]) + e.args[0].reason.errno)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("get requests.RequestException: " + str(sys.exc_info()[0]) + e.args[0].reason.errno)
except Exception as e:
    print("get general exception: " + str(sys.exc_info()[0]) + e.args[0].reason.errno)
except:
    # if no connection exception is raised - catch and try again
    print("get general exception2: " + str(sys.exc_info()[0]))

print(response.status_code)
if response.status_code in (200, 201, 202):
    print(response.json())
```

This is the output when exception occur. prints i added - are not written

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oren\anaconda3\envs\v38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Oren\anaconda3\envs\v38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Oren\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher\__main__.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Oren\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher\__main__.py", line 47, in main
    launcher.connect(host, port)
  File "c:\Users\Oren\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.4.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\launcher\__init__.py", line 27, in connect
    sock.connect((host, port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Your error doesn't match the code. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are right. post fixed with working sample code.

Comment: Still, none of the lines in the stack trace appears to be in the code. Anyway, I ran the exact code you posted here and got status code 200

Comment: @Tomerikoo about the stack trace - you are right. opps. because I copied them from the original exeution, not the sample code I extracted to post here. I will fix that. For the issue itself - in most cases it runs smootly. Try rerun few times in a raw. Sometimes it fails  for few minutes, until suddentley it is OK again. But most of the time - there is no exception

Comment: @Tomerikoo trace line updated. Now it show pure execution of the sample code